# AngularJS: Update all objects in $scope simultaneously

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

Say I have an object stored in `$scope` like so:

```
$scope.todo = [
  {
    "title" : "Groceries",
    "todoItems" : [
      {
        "title" : "Milk",
        "status" : "Not Done"
      },
      {
        "title" : "Eggs",
        "status" : "Not Done"
      },
      {
        "title" : "Bread",
        "status" : "Done"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "title" : "Medical",
    "todoItems" : [
      {
        "title" : "Make eye doctor appointment",
        "status" : "Not Done"
      },
      {
        "title" : "Go to pharmacy",
        "status" : "Not Done"
      },
      {
        "title" : "Take vitamins",
        "status" : "Done"
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

I am creating a feature that allows inline editing of each todo item, like so:

[image]

I achieve this by toggling a property on the todo list item called editMode.  See lines 11-14 in the following code block:

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="dashBoard">
    <div class="panel panel-default list-[(listID)]" ng-repeat="(listID, todoList) in todo" ng-cloak>
      <div class="panel-heading">[( todoList.title )]</div>
        <ul class="list-group">
          <li ng-repeat="(itemID, todoItem) in todoList.todoItems" data-as-sortable="board.dragControlListeners" data-ng-model="items" class="status-[(todoItem.status)] todo-item todo-item-[(itemID)]" data-as-sortable-item>
            <div class="input-group">
              <span data-as-sortable-item-handle class="input-group-addon">
                <input ng-click="toggleStatus(listID, itemID, todoItem.status)" type="checkbox" ng-checked="todoItem.status == 1">
              </span>
              <span ng-if="!todoItem.editMode" class="todo-item-label-wrapper">
                <div ng-click="toggleEditMode(listID, itemID, 1)" class="todo-item-label">[(todoItem.value)]</div>
              </span>
              <span ng-if="todoItem.editMode" class="todo-input-wrapper">
                <input show-focus="todoItem.editMode" ng-keyup="$event.keyCode == 13 && toggleEditMode(listID, itemID, 0)" type="text" ng-model="todoItem.value" class="form-control">
              </span>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

When any given todo item is clicked, it goes into edit mode.  The todo item stays in edit mode until the user hits enter.  I'd like to make it impossible to have multiple todo items in edit mode at the same time.  If you click on todo item "foo" and then click on todo item "bar", todo item "foo" should switch back to read-only mode.

I am currently achieving this by individually switching every todo item with `angular.forEach()`, e.g.:

```
$scope.toggleEditMode = function(listID, itemID, editMode) {
  $scope.todo[listID].todoItems[itemID].editMode = editMode;

  //Turn off edit mode on every todo item other than the one that was just clicked
  angular.forEach($scope.todo[listID].todoItems, function(todoItem, foreignItemID) {
    if (foreignItemID !== itemID) {
      $scope.todo[listID].todoItems[foreignItemID].editMode = 0;
    }
  });
}
```

But I wonder if angular has some utility for this usecase that I should be using.

Comment: Add ng-readonly="!todoItem.editMode" on your input for text

Comment: you can use ng-blur. Make it view only when you focus it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I do in such a case is not having an `editMode` property on each item, but instead using a scope variable like `$scope.currentEditItemId`. Then you do something like this:

```
$scope.toggleEditMode = function (listID, itemID, enableEdit) {
    if (enableEdit === 1) {
        $scope.currentEditItemId = itemId;
        // ... whatever you need to do here
    }
}
```

And the HTML would look like this:

```
<span ng-if="itemId != currentEditItemId" class="todo-item-label-wrapper">
    <div ng-click="toggleEditMode(listID, itemID, 1)" class="todo-item-label">[(todoItem.value)]</div>
</span>
<span ng-if="itemId == currentEditItemId" class="todo-input-wrapper">
    <input show-focus="todoItem.id == currentEditItemId" ng-keyup="$event.keyCode == 13 && toggleEditMode(listID, itemID, 0)" type="text" ng-model="todoItem.value" class="form-control">
</span>
```

Comment: Thanks, that's a great solution.  While it doesn't technically do what I was looking for, it does make the thing I asked for unnecessary.  If no one else replies with a method to do the thing originally discussed in the issue description, I will mark this as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Revisiting this a bit, I realize one way you could update everything in the scope simultaneously is to instantiate each item in `$scope` through a constructor, and then update the constructor prototype.  This doesn't really solve for the original use case I posed above (which is perhaps better stated as "update all items in scope *except one*") but I think it still has some useful applications.

So, if you want to have an item which, when clicked, updates lots of other items, you could do something like this:

**HTML:**

```
  <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="toDo">
    <div ng-click="toggleEdit(index)" ng-class="{{item.editable}}"  ng-repeat="(index, item) in items"> {{item.title}} </div>
  </div>
```

**JS:**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

function newItem(title) {
  this.title = title;
}
newItem.prototype.editable = 'foo';

function toggleAll() {
  newItem.prototype.editable = 'bar';
}

app.controller('toDo', function($scope) {
    $scope.items = []

    for (var i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
      var item = new newItem("item" + i);
      $scope.items.push(item);
    }

    $scope.toggleEdit = function(index) {
      toggleAll();
    }

});
```

**Result:**

Here we see the class `foo` toggle to the class `bar` on all items when any given item is clicked:

[image]